# Using Google+ multiple Gmail Accounts

Tags: google-plus

Is there a way to make a Google+ account work across say 6 different Google email accounts or do you have to to create a new Google+ account for each email account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (and IMHO unfortunately), the answer is NO.  A Google+ account is associated with one, and only one, Google account!

However, at least according to what is written on [just-ask-kim.com](http://just-ask-kim.com/solve-the-google-single-account-rule-for-multiple-gmail-app-accounts/) ("Like Facebook, Google+ has a strict single-account policy"), the alternative that you propose, of creating multiple Google+ accounts, might violate the Google TOS and cause your Google+ account to get banned.

On the other hand, [SocialTimes.com](http://socialtimes.com/google-users-hate-juggling-multiple-accounts-love-hangouts_b127152), seems to accept as fact that Google's current design "forces users to have multiple profiles on Google+."  And this article on [iteachithink.com](http://www.iteachithink.com/2013/04/solve-multiple-google-accounts-problem.html) contains a recommendation on how to mitigate this problem.

The "official" Google directive, as explained on [Mashable.com](http://mashable.com/2012/07/12/google-merge-accounts/#337599-Use-Circles), is to use Google Takeout to merge multiple Google+ accounts into a single Google+ account -- ultimately associated with ***one*** of your Google accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting response and links.  I think that I am like one of the commentators at the conference inasmuch as I have created a bunch of new gmail accounts for personal and different business ventures rather than trying to separately label different types of incoming mail because the same people write to me about different projects.  I use the labels extensively within each account but (provided my correspondents use the correct addresses there is no confusion with subject matter (except with sub topics from the same sender). This all led to the question about google+. T/ks

Comment: Be happy to; how do I do that?

Comment: Click the "check mark" to the left of my answer (and if you wish, also the "up arrow"). :-)

Comment: Done with pleasure.